# Timezone aware objects in Django - why is datetime.time not timezone aware?

Tags: python

I was struggling to understand why the times were displaying an hour early on the website I'm building, but I've now figured it out I think.

I was displaying the 'datetime' by splitting up the object (in my template) into date.day, date.month, date.year and date.time. The date.time was then not being timezone converted (from the UTC value in the database). In London the time zone is currently UTC+1 due to daylight savings, so the times displayed on the website were an hour slower than those I put into the admin interface. I then discovered that if, in the template, I just put {{ date }}, then the times **are** localised.

Is this expected behaviour? Why is date.time not timezone aware?

Thanks

```
{% load tz %}

        Timezone conversion on:<br> 
        {% localtime on %}
            {{ event.date }} 
                {# time converted correctly #}
            <br>
            {{ event.date.day }}/{{ event.date.month }}/{{ event.date.year }}, {{ event.date.time }}
                {# time not converted  #}
            <br>
        {% endlocaltime %}

        Timezone conversion off:<br>
        {% localtime off %}
            {{ event.date }}
                {# time not converted, as expected as timezone conversion is off #}
            <br>
            {{ event.date.day }}/{{ event.date.month }}/{{ event.date.year }}, {{ event.date.time }}
                {# time not converted, as expected as timezone conversion is off #}
            <br>
        {% endlocaltime %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Time is an illusion. Lunchtime doubly so.

If you think about it, there's a good reason for times to not have a timezone. Indeed, how can a *time* be aware of the timezone. By itself it's impossible. Time is just a number. It's like asking how tall you are. If you replied, "42," how am I to know if you mean inches, centimeters, or feet? By itself the number is meaningless. It's only once you introduce a point of reference that it makes sense. And worse, if you said `42` and I was thinking about the wrong units (say, mm) then I would imagine an entirely wrong thing.

So on to time - what does the time represent? It's actually just relative to midnight*. But *which* midnight? Without a date, it could be the most recent midnight, or the midnight a fortnight ago. You don't know. There's no point of reference. It's like `42`. `42` *what*? `13:00` *when*?

And that's where timezones come in. We've (mostly) agreed as society that we want `12:00` to roughly correspond to the Sun at its zenith. After all, we need to know when lunchtime is.

But if you're in Britain (GMT+0), you hardly want to be eating your lunch at the same time I'm eating mine in Arkansas, USA (GMT-6). That'd put you eating lunch when the Sun goes down and that's just crazy talk.

So timezones allow us a way to talk about things in a sensible way - when we say, "lunchtime", we all know that means when the Sun is up high - around `12:00`. As we're *usually* talking about the current lunchtime (I mean, as long as you have your priorities straight) we have a tendency to think about the time meaning *today*. But for computers, lunch is much less important so they only way they're going to know if we meant `12:00` today (December 24, 2015) or lunch tomorrow (December 25, 2015 - hooray Christmas!**) is to explicitly tell it. And the only way it's going to know if we meant lunch here in Arkansas, or lunch in Cape Town, South Africa is if we give it a time zone.

So no, **time not being timezone aware is not a bug**.

If you want to change the timezone you'll need to do that on the datetime, and then get the resulting time from *that*.

*<sup><sub>Sure you could argue from any other point, and you'd also be right!</sub></sup>

**<sup><sub>If you're into that sort of thing.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Unless a datetime object is localized, it is 'unaware'. It knows the time, but not relevant time (e.g. 09:00 in London and San Francisco are the same, despite the 8 hour time difference).

You need to explicitly set the time zone yourself.

```
from pytz import timezone
import datetime as dt

tz = timezone('UTC')
>>> print(dt.datetime.now());print(dt.datetime.now(tz))
2015-12-24 07:29:09.758346
2015-12-24 15:29:09.758426+00:00
```

You cannot make time itself timezone aware.  How would it know on which day to adjust for daylight savings?

> The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC,
>   converting to localtime only when generating output to be read by
>   humans.

Refer to the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net) module for additional examples.

Comment: The datetime object is timezone aware (isn't it?) anyway as event.date is localised, as mentioned above. However, event.date.time is not - I was wondering if this discrepancy is a bug?

Comment: It is not a bug.  Time itself cannot be tz aware.  See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` objects can be timezone-aware if you provide that information with the [`datetime.timezone` class](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects). You can programatically determine the local offset by comparing local time with UTC time (e.g. [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects) vs [`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow)).

Comment: The datetime object is timezone aware anyway (I think?) as event.date is localised, as mentioned above. However, event.date.time is not - I was wondering if this is a bug.